# How to specify build configuration for aspnet core project on Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

For ASP.NET projects, I could setup a application setting with key SCM_BUILD_ARGS and value -p:Configuration="Debug" to change de build configuration. 
That doesn't seem to work for aspnet core 1.1 projects. 
How to specify the build configuration in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the deploy.cmd file download from the KUDU, you will find .net core application is not as same as .net application.

The deploy.cmd file as below:

You will find the SCM_BUILD_ARGS.

```
:: 1. Restore NuGet packages
IF /I "Documents\Visual" NEQ "" (
  call :ExecuteCmd nuget restore "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Documents\Visual"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)

:: 2. Build to the temporary path
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%MSBUILD_PATH%" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Documents\Visual" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Documents\\" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
) ELSE (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%MSBUILD_PATH%" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Documents\Visual" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Documents\\" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
)

IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 3. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)
```

.net Core deployment:

It doesn't contain the SCM_BUILD_ARGS.

```
echo Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.

:: 1. Restore nuget packages
call :ExecuteCmd dotnet restore "WebCoreGitDeploy.sln"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 2. Build and publish
call :ExecuteCmd dotnet publish "WebCoreGitDeploy\WebCoreGitDeploy.csproj" --output "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" --configuration Release
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 3. KuduSync
call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
```

So if you want to change the configuration, you could just download the deployment file and change deploy.cmd's configuration tag to Debug.

I suggest you could firstly push the project to the azure web app. Then you could download the deployment script from kudu.

At last add these file to your project's root path and use git add command to add the file to the git and push.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Open the KUDU

[image]

2.Download the deploy script.

[image]

3.Use notepad to open the deploy.cmd and Change the configuration as below

[image]

4.Then git add changed file.

[image]

5.At last, you push the git.